# Creating Multiple Tiers of Pricing By User Role for WooCommerce/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
<?php

/** This will be the beginning of the Variation Pricing Functions-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/** this checks if the current user is capable to have the reseller pricing
*/

function sfprice_administrator_applicable(){
    return (bool) ( current_user_can('Administrator') && ( !is_admin() || is_ajax() ) );
}
function sfprice_resellerplus_applicable(){
    return (bool) ( current_user_can('resellerplus') && ( !is_admin() || is_ajax() ) );
}
function sfprice_reseller_applicable(){
    return (bool) ( current_user_can('reseller') && ( !is_admin() || is_ajax() ) );
}
function sfprice_corporateplus_applicable(){
    return (bool) ( current_user_can('corporateplus') && ( !is_admin() || is_ajax() ) );
}
function sfprice_smallbusiness_applicable(){
    return (bool) ( current_user_can('smallbusiness') && ( !is_admin() || is_ajax() ) );
}


/** this get the reseller price when available for both Simple & Variable product type
*/

function sfprice_get_administrator_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_administrator_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_administrator_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_administrator_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_administrator_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}
function sfprice_get_resellerplus_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_resellerplus_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_resellerplus_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_resellerplus_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_resellerplus_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}
function sfprice_get_reseller_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_reseller_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_reseller_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_reseller_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_reseller_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}
function sfprice_get_corporateplus_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_corporateplus_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_corporateplus_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_corporateplus_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_corporateplus_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}
function sfprice_get_corporate_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_corporate_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_corporate_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_corporate_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_corporate_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}
function sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_smallbusiness_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_smallbusiness_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_smallbusiness_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_smallbusiness_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}



/** First, we need to add reseller Pricing input to the product editing page. Here’s the code –
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'sfprice_woocommerce_product_options_pricing' );
function sfprice_woocommerce_product_options_pricing()
{
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_administrator_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_administrator_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Administrator Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
      woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_resellerplus_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_resellerplus_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Reseller Plus Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
      woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_reseller_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_reseller_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Reseller Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
      woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_corporateplus_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_corporateplus_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Corporate Plus Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
      woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_corporate_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_corporate_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Corporate Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
      woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_smallbusiness_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_smallbusiness_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Small Business Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
}


/** This code will save the entered value for reseller price with the product with a custom meta ‘_reseller_price’.
*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'sfprice_woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 10, 1 );
function sfprice_woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple( $product_id )
{
    if( isset($_POST['_administrator_price']) && $_POST['_administrator_price'] > 0 )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_administrator_price', $_POST['_administrator_price'] );
    if( isset($_POST['_resellerplus_price']) && $_POST['_resellerplus_price'] > 0 )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_resellerplus_price', $_POST['_resellerplus_price'] );
    if( isset($_POST['_reseller_price']) && $_POST['_reseller_price'] > 0 )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_reseller_price', $_POST['_reseller_price'] );
    if( isset($_POST['_corporateplus_price']) && $_POST['_corporateplus_price'] > 0 )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_corporateplus_price', $_POST['_corporateplus_price'] );
    if( isset($_POST['_corporate_price']) && $_POST['_corporate_price'] > 0 )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_corporate_price', $_POST['_corporate_price'] );
    if( isset($_POST['_smallbusiness_price']) && $_POST['_smallbusiness_price'] > 0 )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_smallbusiness_price', $_POST['_smallbusiness_price'] );
}


/** Now, to Assign the price for each user type we will need to hook into woocommerce_get_price filter.
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'sfprice_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 2);
function sfprice_woocommerce_get_price( $price, $product )
{
if (sfprice_administrator_applicable() && sfprice_get_administrator_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_administrator_price($product);
    return $price; 
} elseif (sfprice_resellerplus_applicable() && sfprice_get_resellerplus_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_resellerplus_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_reseller_applicable() && sfprice_get_reseller_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_reseller_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_corporateplus_applicable() && sfprice_get_corporateplus_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_corporateplus_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_corporate_applicable() && sfprice_get_corporate_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_corporate_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_smallbusiness_applicable() && sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price($product);
    return $price;
}
}

/** The above described method is only for Simple Product. The same feature can be added for Variable Product also, read further below.
*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'sfprice_woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 10, 3 );
function sfprice_woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes( $loop, $variation_data, $variation )
{ ?>
    <tr class="administrator_price_row">
        <td>
            <div>
                <label><?php _e( 'Administrator Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="variable_administrator_price[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php if ( isset( $variation_data['_administrator_price'][0] ) ) echo esc_attr( $variation_data['_administrator_price'][0] ); ?>" step="1" min="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="resellerplus_price_row">
        <td>
            <div>
                <label><?php _e( 'Reseller Plus Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="variable_resellerplus_price[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php if ( isset( $variation_data['_resellerplus_price'][0] ) ) echo esc_attr( $variation_data['_resellerplus_price'][0] ); ?>" step="1" min="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="reseller_price_row">
        <td>
            <div>
                <label><?php _e( 'Reseller Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="variable_reseller_price[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php if ( isset( $variation_data['_reseller_price'][0] ) ) echo esc_attr( $variation_data['_reseller_price'][0] ); ?>" step="1" min="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corporateplus_price_row">
        <td>
            <div>
                <label><?php _e( 'Corporate Plus Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="variable_corporateplus_price[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php if ( isset( $variation_data['_corporateplus_price'][0] ) ) echo esc_attr( $variation_data['_corporateplus_price'][0] ); ?>" step="1" min="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corporate_price_row">
        <td>
            <div>
                <label><?php _e( 'Corporate Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="variable_corporate_price[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php if ( isset( $variation_data['_corporate_price'][0] ) ) echo esc_attr( $variation_data['_corporate_price'][0] ); ?>" step="1" min="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smallbusiness_price_row">
        <td>
            <div>
                <label><?php _e( 'Small Business Price:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="variable_smallbusiness_price[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php if ( isset( $variation_data['_smallbusiness_price'][0] ) ) echo esc_attr( $variation_data['_smallbusiness_price'][0] ); ?>" step="1" min="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}


/** Saving the price
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'sfprice_woocommerce_save_product_variation', 10, 2 );
function sfprice_woocommerce_save_product_variation($variation_id, $i)
{
    if( isset($_POST['variable_administrator_price'][$i]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_administrator_price', $_POST['variable_administrator_price'][$i]);
    if( isset($_POST['variable_resellerplus_price'][$i]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_resellerplus_price', $_POST['variable_resellerplus_price'][$i]);
    if( isset($_POST['variable_reseller_price'][$i]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_reseller_price', $_POST['variable_reseller_price'][$i]);
    if( isset($_POST['variable_corporateplus_price'][$i]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_corporateplus_price', $_POST['variable_corporateplus_price'][$i]);
    if( isset($_POST['variable_corporate_price'][$i]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_corporate_price', $_POST['variable_corporate_price'][$i]);
    if( isset($_POST['variable_smallbusiness_price'][$i]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_smallbusiness_price', $_POST['variable_smallbusiness_price'][$i]);
}
```

Above is the created code for a 6 tiered pricing system for WooCommerce/Wordpress. Simple Products are functioning properly and prior to adding all 6  when only 1 new tier of pricing with role association was created this code worked for variation products as well.

I am having a hard time locating the issue in the code but it still works with simple products; but again is failing to load product pages for variation products as well as show the saved pricing per variation on backend.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Also nothing is being generated in the log files as an error.

Thanks,

Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a function `sfprice_corporate_applicable()`

In your script you are trying to access that function, but it doesn't exist in your project.

so create the new function like so

```
function sfprice_corporate_applicable() {
    return (bool) ( current_user_can('corporate') && ( !is_admin() || is_ajax() ) );
}
```

Comment: This definitely resolved some major issues! It looks like i have a few more in the waiting wing though. Thanks Joshua!